# Remember login from WordPress password protected page

Tags: wordpress

I know how to password protect a page and check if it has been entered with post_password_required. What I need to know is if I can then continue to know if a user has logged into this password protected page even after leaving it. The reason for this is because I would like to display a site wide navigational sidebar that allows the user to get back to that page, but only have it show if they have logged into that page earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a session variable if they login successively to the given page, then when they are on another page later, have the sidebar echo the link if that session var is set.

The value of the session var can be the url to create the link, if you have more than one page you're trying to do this with.

Comment: Will give this a try, I was hoping there was some built in functionality for this. A cookie is actually set when a successful login to a password page happens, I could also use this.